# Write SQL query for the given scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

We have a table without date or incremental int column as below.

```
create table test(
id uniqueidentifier DEFAULT newsequentialid(),
userid int, 
type int, 
value varchar(20)
);
```

We wanted userid with value based on following logic, **first** data in case of primary else **last** data in case of other type.

```
Available type column value 
-------------
0 - None
1 - Primary
2 - Other
3 - Registered

Logic to retrieve value should be as below : 

if Primary available : 
    take "first" Primary's Value 
else if Registered available :
    take "last" Registered's Value
else if Other available :
    take "last" Other's Value
else 
    take "last" None's Value
```

Created few scenarios to understand requirement better.

Scenario 1 :

```
/*
Output should be as below
userid, value 
-------------
1, User1 value1.1
2, User2 value4.2
*/
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(1, 1, 'User1 value1.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(1, 1, 'User1 value1.2')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(1, 2, 'User1 value2.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(1, 2, 'User1 value2.2')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(1, 4, 'User1 value4.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(1, 4, 'User1 value4.2')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(2, 0, 'User2 value0.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(2, 0, 'User2 value0.2')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(2, 4, 'User2 value4.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(2, 4, 'User2 value4.2')
```

Scenario 2 :

```
/* 
Output should be as below
userid, value 
-------------
3, User3 value1.1
4, User4 value4.2
*/
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(3, 0, 'User3 value0.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(3, 1, 'User3 value1.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(3, 2, 'User3 value2.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(3, 2, 'User3 value2.2')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(4, 4, 'User4 value4.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(4, 4, 'User4 value4.2')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(4, 2, 'User4 value2.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(4, 0, 'User4 value0.1')
```

Scenario 3  :

```
/* 
Output should be as below
userid, value 
-------------
5, User5 value2.1
6, User6 value0.3
*/
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(5, 2, 'User1 value1.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(5, 2, 'User1 value2.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(5, 0, 'User1 value0.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(6, 0, 'User6 value0.1')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(6, 0, 'User6 value0.2')
insert into test (userid, type, value) values(6, 0, 'User6 value0.3')
```

Highly appreciate any help.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id
                                order by (case when type = 1 then 1 when type = 3 then 2 when type = 2 then 3 else 4 end),
                                         (case when type = 1 then id end) asc,
                                         id desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from test t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: No its not what i expect....please check the expected result and logic (First it should take Primary if available else Registered else Other)

Comment: @rajusem . . . I think the tweak to the `order by` does what you want.

Comment: tried different way but still not got a way to make it work.